# Programmatically determine VGA or DVI on a primary monitor using Windows API?

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn, vga

If I can get a handle to a monitor and get the monitor's info using the handle and the "GetMonitorInfo" function from the windows API, is there some way I can determine more info like whether that monitor is using the DVI or the VGA port?  Or what that device's name is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a direct way to retrieve the type of port used. About the best I know of is that you can use WMI to enumerate objects of the [`Win32_DesktopMonitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394122.aspx) class, and guess at the connection based on the `bandwidth` property.

If you're willing to do a fair amount of work, you can sometimes improve your guess by enumerating [`Win32_VideoController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394512.aspx) objects. Some controllers only have VGA, and others only have DVI -- but if you get a controller that supports both, you're probably back to guessing based on the stated bandwidth (which may not be supplied either).

Comment: Yeah that looks like that's what I'm gonna have to do, I was hoping there was something easier but MSDN leaves a lot to be desired.  Thanks you!